# Error for GDAL merge in QGIS 3 for missing Python3.6 on Mac 10.11.6

Tags: python, gis, raster, gdal

I have installed Python 3.6 on my Mac, GDAL and QGIS 3.0. But if I use a tool, like merge raster from GDAL, QGIS stops the work and says: "env: python3.6: No such file or directory" 
I have set Python and GDAL to my $PATH, and added the Values in QGIS-Settings, too.
How can I stop getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to append `:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/` to your $PATH env variable in the settings.

If you've already append `:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs` it should be `:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/` in QGIS settings.